# Eclipse deprecated code highlighting php

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, deprecated

I have two different pcs with identical Eclipse installs on them. One shows me deprecated functions as a strikethrough ie <strike>foo()</strike>. However, on my other pc this doesn't seem to work. I've tried changing the preferences to no avail. Also I've noticed that when I show the function definition by holding `ctrl` and clicking on the function (in this case `ereg_replace()`) there is no `@deprecated` line or anything. Am I missing something?

Also I am using the EclipseColorTheme plugin on both pcs; not sure if that would affect it.

Comment: Do the versions of the plugin match?

Comment: yes they do that's part of why I'm stumped. every version matches. PDT EcipseColorTheme and Eclipse itself.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but in case anyone else comes across this:

Preferences->PHP->Editor->Syntax Coloring. Select Deprecated members. Select enabled. It will allow you to format the highlighting (Strike Through).