# Eclipse - PHP deprecated commands not being highlighted

Tags: php, eclipse, deprecated

I have setup a PHP project in Eclipse which features a number of deprecated functions, such as `mysql_connect()`, and I would like for Eclipse to highlight these deprecated functions and flag them as errors in the Problems tab.

Unfortunately I have not been able to get this feature up and running. I have tried the advice posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280497/7155133) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18094135/7155133) but with no success.

I am using Eclipse version 2019-06 (4.12.0) and PHP version 7.3.8.

Is there a way to make these deprecated/outdated functions flag an error in Eclipse? Are they maybe not being flagged because in PHP 7.3.8 the `mysql_connect()` function isn't just deprecated but it just doesn't even exist?

Answer (score 0):

In current version, Eclipse PDT haven't such feature. Our library stubs haven't @deprecated flag.

You can create feature request here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT